# How to set-up LuaTeX, Microtype, with Minion Pro, Myriad Pro

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, microtype

Since recently I am using LuaLaTeX with the most recent beta version of Microtype, along with the fonts Minion Pro and Myriad Pro. In the manual of Microtype it says:

```
    Currently, this package provides protrusion settings for [...] Adobe Garamond and Minion, [...] as well as some generic settings for unknown fonts
(cf. table 3 on page 21)
```

Currently, I just include the fonts like this (with some other font definitions for headings etc. settings left out here):

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=6}, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[LetterSpace=3, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Myriad Pro}
```

But this way I still get the following message from `Microtype`:

```
Package microtype Warning: Loading generic settings for font family `MinionPro'
```

How can I load the correct settings? Also, is there a way to avoid all these warnings I get for fonts that are not supported, and Microtype just loads the generic settings?

Comment: AFAIK the default settings of `microtype` are for the Type1 variant of traditional LaTeX. Since you're using `LuaLaTeX` and `fontspec` you're probably using a much newer OpenType version of the fonts. Therefore the settings `microtype` comes with are useless for you. You need completely new ones – which don't exist yet, at least not publicly.

Comment: If that is the case, just copy your comment in an answer and I'll accept it for as long as no real solution exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the current microtype from TeXlive 2011, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}


\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=6}, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[LetterSpace=3, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Myriad Pro}


\SetProtrusion
   [ name     = min-eu2 ]
   { encoding = {EU2},
     family   = MinionPro  }
   {
     {,} = {  ,500},
      -  = {  ,500}
   }


\begin{document}
  \hsize 3in

When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable
foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the
trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me.

\end{document}
```

LuaTeX with fontspec uses EU2 encoding internally, so all you need to do is the regular microtype setup with encoding EU2.

Comment: The setting `.  = {  ,500},`  should also be used. However it makes no real difference to the output without `\SetProtrusion`

Comment: Should we use microtype or rely on the options offered by LuaTeX through luaotfload?

Answer (score 18):

Hm, I also use Minion Pro and Myriad Pro … this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Microtype,Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Myriad Pro}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Than TeX Live 2010 and now 2011.

Comment: Nice solution, easier than mine.

Comment: Well, I have to state that I did not invent this by my own, but in de.comp.text.tex someone gave me a hint and it worked like a charm.

Comment: “Someone” was Ulrike Fischer, IIRC. You should add a remark, that your solution doesn’t make use of the package `microtype`. Or am I wrong (question @LuaTEXperts)?

Comment: Well, as I had not asked her if she'd agree that I post her name, and as I was not quite shure I preferred “someone”, you seem to know and have asked her. And I was thinking about that `microtype` exactly as you mentioned … but I am not quite sure (again) due to microtype is mentioned. So, I'm not so deep into it to judge if it's the same `microtype`. But I know that this way is a grandious solution to use those two fonts with . And that's the reason I mentioned it here.

Comment: Ulrike is active here, too, so I don’t see a problem. Concerning `microtype`: The OP wrote about the package, your solution does not use it – that’s the only thing, what I wanted to remark. OTOH I do not know, whether the package has more features now in the beta version. For that we need a person, that I've called “LuaTeXpert”.

Answer (score 1):

The user guide for version 2.5/beta08 of the microtype package states that the `kerning`, `spacing`, and `tracking` options are not (yet) functional if microtype is used with Lua(La)TeX. It may well be the case that other capabilities -- such as the ability to load specialized configurations via .cfg files -- aren't fully functional either when used with Lua(La)TeX.

At any rate, what you're getting is not an error message but "just" a warning message. You may wish to send the author of the microtype package a message to inquire if and when an updated version of the file `mt-MinionPro.cfg` might become available; the file that currently comes with the package has a file date of 2005/02/07.

Comment: Can I get kerning and tracking with another package or with any option in Luatex?

Comment: @skan - (First off, do note that this answer is nearly 5 years old by now.) According to the user guide of the current version of `microtype` (version 2.6a, May 2016), tracking *is* available under LuaLaTeX by now. However, kerning and spacing still aren't available. If you're very good at Lua programming, LuaTeX does provide a full interface for writing kerning and spacing functions. To my knowledge, though, there are no LaTeX packages yet -- ConTeXt may be a different matter -- that have implemented kerning and spacing in a user-friendly way.