# How to set expansion and protrusion for TeX Gyre Pagella using LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, microtype, protrusion, font-expansion

For my documents, I have often used the `mathpazo` package combined with `microtype` and have found the result to be really good. Because now I need to create PDFs which contain a variety of diacritics and which should be easy to copy from, I have decided to use LuaTeX with TeX Gyre Pagella.

Initially I had difficulty getting `microtype` to work, but thanks to Alabay's answer in [How to set-up LuaTeX, Microtype, with Minion Pro, Myriad Pro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40671/how-to-set-up-luatex-microtype-with-minion-pro-myriad-pro) I have made it. Still, I'm struggling with protrusion settings.

Given the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;} 
\setmainfont[Microtype,Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

LuaTeX produces this:
[image: Protrusion in TeX Gyre Pagella -- LuaTeX]

I must say I don't quite like the fact that the punctuation marks protrude so far from the margin. Is there a way I can change the default settings? I have tried to do this in various ways (e.g. by changing `factor` in `microtype`), but to no success. Ideally, I would like to get a similar result as when I run pdfTeX with `mathpazo`:

[image: Protrusion of mathpazo -- pdfTeX]

Another (but related) thing is setting expansion for TeX Gyre Pagella. Can I do it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the default factor like this (5 is not a sensible value but shows the effect quite good:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}

\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=5}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

For a more fine grained change you should copy the default table from `otfl-font-dum.lua`  (`fonts.protrusions.setups['default']`). Move it to e.g. `prottest.lua`, change `default` to `test`, adapt the values and then use it like this:

```
\directlua{require("prottest.lua");}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=test;expansion=default;}
```

(I didn't test this recently so I'm not sure if this still works.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! :) I have written 0.5 as the factor and the document already looks a whole lot better. Thanks to your code, it has also been easy to find a way of manipulating expansion – e.g. by writing `\directlua{fonts.expansions.setups.default.stretch=1.5}`. Now I'm happy with these basic changes, but might need the fine-tuning in the future, so I'm grateful for the additional information, too.