# Microtypesets and Fontspec

Tags: fontspec, microtype

Is there a way to use Microtypesets so that one would specify a fontspec family.

I have a very complicated document and it would be nice to be able to turn the microtype features on only for those pieces of text that need it. Using size, or font isn't really ideal.

Something like:

```
\newfontfamily{\textwithexpansion}
[size=.8,
stretch=1000,
Color=Laud_red]
{ArnoPro-italic}
```

failing that then just a way to turn off and on the microtype settings.

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40671)

Comment: it's similar but it seems like they are doing global settings, where I would like something more specific to the various areas of my layout.

Comment: (Oops.  I deleted my comment....) Load the same font twice, just under different names.  In one of them you can use some of the 'font independent options' like `WordSpace`.  Microtype also lets you `\SetProtrusion` according to `encoding` and `family`.

Comment: Thanks Jon could you provide an example of what you mean so I can see if that is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`microtype`'s sets also accept the `font` key to include single fonts, so you could for example say:

```
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[expansion]{theobear}
    { font = {*/*/*/it*/*, */*/bf*/*/*} }
```

which would enable expansion only for the bold and the italic main font in the current size. (The asterisk `*` is a shortcut for the respective default, so the line above would expand to, e.g., `EU1/ArnoPro/m/it/10, EU1/ArnoPro/bx/n/10`.)

To turn `microtype` on and off within the document, just issue the command

```
\microtypesetup{expansion=false} % "=true" to switch on again
```